# Is there a function in excel that compares two similar (but not the same) cells and outputs a yes or no?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

I have a checking column built, with the intention of confirming two company names are the same. The two company names come from different programs, thus showing different formatting.

For example - BLACKROCK TRUST, INC. vs. Blackrock trust 1156

These are both the same company, so I wanted a column confirming "yes" these are the same because they share a certain percentage of the same characters. I tried transforming the company names, but this file is rather large, and has thousands of companies.

Thank you for any help!

I tried a number of IF based statements, but I feel like there is something easier that I am missing? My excel skills are rather intermediate, but not to the point of using VBA or something macro related.

Comment: Short answer - no. There is now built in function to get the result you desire. Either you need to use 3rd party addons or to use VBA (there are solutions beyond SO)

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this before. Depending on how cumbersome are willing to get with "helper" columns that you can hide, I suggest the following answer using intermediate excel skills to test the similarity of two strings. The core assumption is that the first characters of the name will generally be the same and the differences will be in the formatting, suffix, or non-informative characters

Step 1: Create a helper column for each name with the following formula:
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(TRIM(CLEAN(A10)))," ","")
This will remove spaces and make each string lower case. You could also substitute "" for other non-distinguishing characters or strings in your data if they are common (for example, ",inc" ",llc" "." "," etc.).

Step 2: you now have two modified strings (let's say they are in cells C10 and D10). Populate cells E9:V9 with a sequentially increasing number, e.g. 3 4 5 6 ....

Step 3: Populate cells E10:V10 with the following formula to compare the first N characters of each string, where N is the values you have in cells E9:V9
=IF(EXACT(LEFT($C10,E$9),LEFT($D10,E$9)),E$9/MIN(LEN($C10),LEN($D10)))
This will tell you the % of leading characters that are the same between the two strings

Step 4: Select a threshold for likely match and populate column W with the following
=MAX(E10:V10)>0.8
This will indicate true for any two strings that match at least 80% of the leading characters. Your blackrock example only matched 78%, so 80% may be too high of a threshold but you can also flag ones that are close and check those manually

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out, I appreciate the quick response.